# C# Generics Constraints: Is there a way to express is not a?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints

I have the following code:

```
interface IConverter<T, U>
{
    U Convert(T obj);
}

interface IBusinessEntityConveter<T, U> : IConverter<T, U>
    where U : BusinessEntity
{
}

class LookupConveter<B> : IBusinessEntityConveter<Lookup, B>, IConverter<Lookup, Moniker>
    where B : BusinessEntity, new()
{

    #region IConverter<Lookup, Moniker> Members

    public Moniker Convert(Lookup obj)
    {
       //...
    }

    #endregion


    #region IConverter<Lookup,B> Members

    public B Convert(Lookup obj)
    {
       //...
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Error 2   '`Convertors.LookupConveter<B>`'
>   cannot implement both
>   '`Convertors.IConverter<Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Lookup,B>`'
>   and
>   '`Convertors.IConverter<Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Lookup,Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Moniker>`'
>   because they may unify for some type
>   parameter
>   substitutions

Is there a way to specify that T isn't a business entity?

Comment: You are breaking rule #1 of overloading, you cant overload methods just based on the return type. This fails long before the generics issue.

Comment: @Ieppie: What? What does that have to do with the error message?

Comment: @Timwi: Even if you could fudge the generics issue, it will still fail due to 'broken' overload.

Comment: Even if there was a way to specify that `T` isn’t a `BusinessEntity`, you would still have the problem. The problem is that I could declare a `LookupConverter<Moniker>` and then that would have to implement two copies of `IConverter<Lookup, Moniker>`, which would make the class’s behaviour ambiguous.

Comment: @Timwi: I do not disagree with you. Just pointing out the obvious error with the overload being broken. Why the compiler is not stabbing the user, is beyond me.

Comment: @Ieppie: It’s because you got the causality the wrong way around. The overload issue is a consequence of the generics problem, not the other way around. (P.S. the previous comment was intended for the OP)

Comment: The overload issue could be addressed by explicitly implementing one of the interfaces.  If that is acceptable, then it is a non-issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, I'm afraid not. The only options you have are listed here [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). In summary these are:

- enforce a value type
- enforce a reference type
- enforce a non reference type, which contains no reference types
- enforce a public parameterless constructor
- enforce a specific base class
- enforce a specific interface
- enforce type derives from an argument

Answer (score 4):

No, there are no "negative" constraints.

Comment: How would you go around this unability to express resolvance of conflicgs?

Comment: @the_drow: It's hard to say without knowing why you want the same type to convert generically and the specific type.

Comment: A lookup is a type/id tuple that represents a record in the database, converting it to a real type involves accessing a web service and fetching an xml file that is serialized to a DynamicEntity, I then convert the DynamicEntity (which is a BusinessEntity) to a home-coocked strong type. A lookup can also be converted to a moniker which is practically the same as a lookup but with less features and it is used somewhere else in the system and thus I would like to convert it easily. **This is not my code, it's Microsoft Dynamics CRM shitty architecture.** Only the converters are mine.

Comment: @the_drow: Which bit is forcing you to implement both interfaces in the same class though?

Comment: Because they are related, I am trying to have this kind of syntax that could be injected with an IOC container: `IConverter<Lookup, Moniker> converter = new LookupConverter()`. You might be correct though, I just tried to stick with DRY principle. If only I could specialize a generic class...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Would you say that specifying that T is not U is an important feature? Should I go an ask for it in Microsoft Connect? Also got any idea to resolve this issue? Should I just go with separate classes?

Comment: @the_drow: No, I don't think it's an important feature - it would add significant complexity with only very rare benefits, IMO. And yes, just go with separate classes.